Text Next to Rotated Table
I generated a table
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx, color}
\usepackage[pdfa,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\geometry{textheight=24.2cm,right=3cm, left=3cm, bottom=2.5cm, head=2cm,headsep=1cm}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % Table Scaling Ansatz
%\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{11pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    {\rowcolors{2}{gray!10!white!100}{gray!25!white!100}
    \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
    \Rotatebox{90}{
    \begin{tabular}{
    |P{2.4cm}|P{2.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{2cm}|P{1.15cm}|P{1.8cm}|P{0.25cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{Scaling Ansatz} \\
        \hline
        & \textbf{Horiz. scale} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{Temp. scale} & \textbf{t} & \textbf{Vert. scale} & \textbf{z} \\
        \hline
        Non-dimens. & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $x$ & $y$ & $t_{\text{ref}}\sim\qty{15}{min}$ & $t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$\\
        Mesoscale & $L_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{150}{km}$ & $x_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,x$ & $y_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,y$ & $T_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{3.5}{h}$ & $t_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        Synoptic Scale & $L_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1100}{km}$ & $x_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,x$ & $y_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,y$ & $T_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1}{d}$ & $t_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}}
    \centering
\end{table}
\end{document}

My question is: How can I move the table to the left side of the page such that I can continue writing at the right side of the page? The table needs to be rotated, the text should not be rotated.

If you know, that not all packages are needed, you should remove the not needed. This could also help, to avoid the error about already defined \iint. → https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

cabohah, thanks, done!

If you transposed the table it would be a lot narrower and thus there would be no need to also rotate it.

Remove the not needed table environment. Than you can, e.g., place a minipage beside the rotated tabular:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}% avoid engine backend options, that are
                            % automatically detected (Note: color not
                            % needed here, because of the later uses
                            % xcolor).
\usepackage[pdfa,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{textheight=24.2cm,right=3cm, left=3cm, bottom=2.5cm, head=2cm,headsep=1cm}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % Table Scaling Ansatz
%\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{11pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}
    \Rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{%
      \rowcolors{2}{gray!10!white!100}{gray!25!white!100}
      \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
      \begin{tabular}{
        |P{2.4cm}|P{2.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{2cm}|P{1.15cm}|P{1.8cm}|P{0.25cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{Scaling Ansatz} \\
        \hline
        & \textbf{Horiz. scale} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{Temp. scale} & \textbf{t} & \textbf{Vert. scale} & \textbf{z} \\
        \hline
        Non-dimens. & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $x$ & $y$ & $t_{\text{ref}}\sim\qty{15}{min}$ & $t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$\\
        Mesoscale & $L_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{150}{km}$ & $x_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,x$ & $y_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,y$ & $T_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{3.5}{h}$ & $t_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        Synoptic Scale & $L_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1100}{km}$ & $x_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,x$ & $y_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,y$ & $T_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1}{d}$ & $t_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.65\textwidth}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{document}


There a many alternatives like placing the rotated box inside a tabularx:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textheight=24.2cm,right=3cm, left=3cm, bottom=2.5cm, head=2cm,headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdfa,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % Table Scaling Ansatz

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{11pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{%
      \rowcolors{2}{gray!10!white!100}{gray!25!white!100}
      \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
      \begin{tabular}{
        |P{2.4cm}|P{2.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{2cm}|P{1.15cm}|P{1.8cm}|P{0.25cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{Scaling Ansatz} \\
        \hline
        & \textbf{Horiz. scale} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{Temp. scale} & \textbf{t} & \textbf{Vert. scale} & \textbf{z} \\
        \hline
        Non-dimens. & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $x$ & $y$ & $t_{\text{ref}}\sim\qty{15}{min}$ & $t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$\\
        Mesoscale & $L_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{150}{km}$ & $x_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,x$ & $y_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,y$ & $T_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{3.5}{h}$ & $t_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        Synoptic Scale & $L_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1100}{km}$ & $x_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,x$ & $y_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,y$ & $T_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1}{d}$ & $t_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}} &
  \Blindtext[3]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}

or using a package like wrapfig2
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textheight=24.2cm,right=3cm, left=3cm, bottom=2.5cm, head=2cm,headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdfa,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % Table Scaling Ansatz

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{11pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{wraptable}{l}
    \rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{%
      \rowcolors{2}{gray!10!white!100}{gray!25!white!100}
      \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
      \begin{tabular}{
        |P{2.4cm}|P{2.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{2cm}|P{1.15cm}|P{1.8cm}|P{0.25cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{Scaling Ansatz} \\
        \hline
        & \textbf{Horiz. scale} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{Temp. scale} & \textbf{t} & \textbf{Vert. scale} & \textbf{z} \\
        \hline
        Non-dimens. & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $x$ & $y$ & $t_{\text{ref}}\sim\qty{15}{min}$ & $t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$\\
        Mesoscale & $L_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{150}{km}$ & $x_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,x$ & $y_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,y$ & $T_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{3.5}{h}$ & $t_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        Synoptic Scale & $L_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1100}{km}$ & $x_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,x$ & $y_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,y$ & $T_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1}{d}$ & $t_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}}
\end{wraptable}
\Blindtext[3]
\end{document}

etc.
